# Zero-coupon Loan Investment

Tags: interest-rates, finance, forward, finance-mathematics, zero-coupon

Zero-coupon default-free interest rates maturing over the next five years are listed below (in percent per annum, continuously-compounded):

Maturity Years -- Yield

1 --------------------1.9

2 --------------------2.2

3 --------------------2.5

4 --------------------2.8

5 --------------------3.4

You expect to inherit $50 million at the end of year two, and would like to invest it for two additional years in the safest possible instrument in real terms. What is the safest investment and its rate of return?

a) Execute a forward loan at 3.4%

b) Lend for four years at 2.8%

c) Execute a forward loan at 3.7%

d) Wait two years and lend for two years

I think I know what to do when the interest rate is constant but I'm not sure what to do when it changes like this. Since the 50$ million inflow is coming in at the end of year 2, do I start looking at the table from year 3?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Anyone have any idea?

Comment: I am voting to close as this is a very basic question and thus off topic. Any introductory textbook will help you here. See e.g. Chapter 4 "Interest Rates" in Hull's "Options Futures and Other Derivatives" and look for "forward rates".

Answer (score 1):

Safest would be FRA to lock the interest rates.

Thanks

Comment: So it would be either A or C? How would I calculate the return in those cases?

Comment: This is really getting too basic.